# Configure a web service w/ Anonymous Access hosted in a Windows Authentication site

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, authentication

I have an application on our intranet that is configured for Anonymous Authentication that needs to consume a web service configured for Windows Authentication.

I have added the following section to the web.config file to allow anonymous access on just the web service:

```
<location path="services/MyApi.asmx">
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <allow users="?" />
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
</location>
```

When I try to consume the web service from the application with anonymous access, I get the following error:

> The request failed with HTTP status 401: Unauthorized.

Here is my source code for consuming the web service:

```
using (MyService.MyApi proxy = new MyService.MyApi())
{
    string employeeId = Session["EmpCode"].ToString();
    proxy.MyMethod(employeeId);
}
```

What do I need to do to resolve this error?

Comment: What framework are you using?

Comment: Have you checked out: (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh556235.aspx)

Comment: So that resources would require me to change my asmx service to WCF service?

Comment: The next step is to see what is denying access, check this out: (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/david.wang/archive/2005/07/14/howto-diagnose-iis-401-access-denied.aspx)

Comment: Not necessarily, it is more as a reference at this point in time.  But also change to reflect this:  <allow users="*" />

Comment: sorry, was a bit confused with the last, you are correct in <allow users="?" />

Comment: Also try and place a web.config in the folder containing the service with the <allow users="?" />

Comment: I believe the windows authentication is rejecting the user before asp.net even gets a chance to check authorization.

Comment: tried web.config w/ <allow users="?" /> in web services directory and it still does not work

Comment: Ok, if that is the case, check out this site (http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/security/authentication/windowsauthentication).  The issue may be that you have Anonomous Authentication as disabled in the server iis itself.

Answer (score 0):

change `?` for `*` in `<allow users="*" />` it will be allow an Anonymous user to the webservice

Comment: <location path="services/MyApi.asmx">
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <allow users="*" />
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
</location>